# Bluemix containers - how have a Linux

Tags: linux, docker, debian, containers, ibm-cloud

I can't start a container on Bluemix with Debian, Centos, Alpine or other. Is there a way or is it blocked?

Image from docker hub.

Is there any getting started for the run command ?

I suppose that i need a file for parameters.

Comment: Can you share some more information about what you're experiencing? What commands are you using? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Big difference between running a container in local docker vs in the container service is that all containers in the container service are effectively running `-d` (i.e. daemon/disconncted mode).  If you're just using the base images you listed, most of those do not have a long running process in the container, and expect that you will be running it interactive.

Result of that is that in the container service, the container starts, then exits again because it's non-interactive, and there's no other process to keep it alive.  You can try adding a wait as the "cmd" for it.

i.e. for your dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
```

build that to your registry, then run with something like `cf ic run --name alpinetest -m 512 registry.ng.bluemix.net/yourregistryhere/alpine sh -c "sleep 1000000"`

Then, to get an interactive shell, you can exec into the container using `cf ic exec -ti alpinetest /bin/sh`

Obviously, to have it do something useful, you're probably going to want to put an actual server running in there as the foreground app, and set that as the CMD or ENTRYPOINT, but that'll give you access to it running to poke at.